# How to store the value in local storage using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use local storage for storing the multistep form values.So here the issue is if i am entering the values at input fields and all the values are storing at local storage. But while I am signing in with other mails then the same value are appearing in the form which is enterd with before mail. So here the same entered value should not appear while we login with other mail. So where i am going wrong please tell me

```
<vue-form-g :schema="schema_Antiques" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-g>
```

```
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',

    components: {
        "vue-form-g": VueFormGenerator.component
    },
    data() {
            return {
                model:{}
            },
schema_Antiques: {
            fields: [{
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Type",
                model: "Type",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Origin",
                required: true,
                model: "Origin",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Age",
                required: true,
                model: "Age",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Condition",
                required: true,
                model: "Condition",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Size",
                required: true,
                model: "Size",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Maker",
                required: true,
                model: "Maker",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-6", "Experience"]
            }, {
                type: "input",
                inputType: "text",
                placeholder: "Material",
                required: true,
                model: "Material",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "job_title"]
            }, {
                type: "textArea",
                model: "Other_specializations",
                max: 500,
                placeholder: "Other specializations",
                styleClasses: ["half-width col-xs-12 col-sm-4", "Experience"]
            }]
        },
        
        mounted() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('model') !== null)
            this.model = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('model'));
        },
        
        methods: {
            localStorage.setItem('model', JSON.stringify(this.model));
        }
```

Comment: Add more details to your post. How is this related to Vue? If you are using local storage, consider creating a [mre]. Learn more at [ask]

Comment: I cannot see a good reason to save form values into local storage, vice versa - sounds like a bad idea. Please explain what exactly you need, sounds to me like a typically [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hi @guyaloni please tell me how to use local storage with vue form generator

Comment: @InayatKazi, please explain what is what you are trying to achieve. And please please use line breaks to make your question more readable....